# Only future dates - validation in Rails model

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord

I have field `date` in the `User` model. It shuld have only future dates (from registration moment). What is the best way to validation it in the model?

I think about something like this:

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true
  validate :future_event


  private

  def future_event
    errors.add(:date, "Can't be in the past!") if date < Time.now
  end
end
```

Is it OK?

Can you think about some more simple and elegant solution?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

```
# lib/future_validator.rb
class FutureValidator < ActiveModel::EachValidator
  def validate_each(record, attribute, value)
    if record[attribute] < Time.now
      record.errors[attribute] << (options[:message] || "can't be in the past!")
    end
  end
end
```

---

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
  validates :name, presence: true
  validates :date, presence: true
  validates :future_event, future: true
end
```

- http://guides.rubyonrails.org/active_record_validations.html#custom-validators

Comment: There must be many gems out there that provide chronological validations for rails however.

Comment: You should given                                                                                                     `if record[attribute] < Time.now`                                                                    instead of                                                                                                            `date < Time.now`

Comment: Is this going to work if the record is validated after the date being checked has passed?

Comment: @DavidAldridge - the validation would not pass if you for example are updating an older record. In that case you might want to do something like: `validates :future_event, future: true, unless: :persisted?`

Comment: @max Probably just want to validate on: :create then.

Answer (score 3):

Take a look at the [Date Validator Gem](https://github.com/codegram/date_validator)

```
validates :start_date,
  date: { after: Proc.new { Date.current }, message: 'must be after today' },
  on: :create
```

You might always want to investigate the differences between `Date.current` and `Date.today` - `Date.current` is timezone aware and will use the Timezone of your Rails app.  `Date.today` uses system time.  There can be odd differences if one is UTC and one is Eastern.

Answer (score 0):

#### Use `inclusion`.

Something like this:

```rb
validates :date, inclusion: { in: Proc.new{ 1.day.from_now.. }, message: "has to be in the future" }
```